$X \in \{-b,0,b\}$ $P$-almost surely if and only if $P(|X| \geq b)=b^{-p}\mathbb{E}|X|^p $
Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$, $X \in \mathcal{L}^p$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$ and $b>0$.
I was able to prove  $X \in \{-b,0,b\}$ $P$-almost surely $\implies$ $P(|X| \geq b)=b^{-p}\mathbb{E}|X|^p $.
But I am having difficulties proving the converse.
My idea is the following: Since $X \in \{-b,0,b\}$ $P$-almost surely is equivalent to:
$$P(X \in \{-b,0,b\})=1$$
That we use the given identity to show $P(X \in \{-b,0,b\}) \geq 1$.
My approach would go like this:
$\begin{align*} P(X \in \{-b,0,b\}) \geq P(|X| = b) &= P(|X| \geq b) - P(|X| > b) \\ &=b^{-p}\mathbb{E}|X|^p - P(|X| > b) \\ &= \int_{\Omega}b^{-p}|X|^pdP-\int_{\Omega}\chi_{\{|X| > b\}} dP \\ &=\int_{\Omega}(b^{-p}|X|^p-1)\chi_{\{|X| > b\}}dP+\int_{\Omega}b^{-p}|X|^p\chi_{\{|X| \leq b\}}dP \\ &> \int_{\Omega}b^{-p}|X|^p\chi_{\{|X| \leq b\}}dP\end{align*}$
But it seems like this does not lead to desired result.
Is there another way to approach this? I would be grateful for any hint.

First note that
$$\int_{|X|\geq b}b^pdP\le\int_{|X|\geq b}|X|^pdP
\le\mathbb{E}(|X|^p).$$
If $P(|X| \geq b)=b^{-p}\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ then these two inequalities become equalities. The first one implies $P(|X|>b)=0$, and the second one implies $P(0<|X|<b)=0$.
